# getting error when i update image in my admin panel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to update my product table but when I update my product table, it throws this error :

> ErrorException in CreatesController.php line 201: Undefined variable:
>   name

```
201 line is this: 'image'=> $name,
```

**My product table contains following fields :**

```
productname,image,price,category_id
```

**This is CreatesController :**

```
public function productupdate(Request $request, $id){

$this->validate($request, [

'productname'=>'required',

'image'=>'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:10000',

'price'=>'required',

'category_id'=>'required'

]);

if($request->hasfile('image'))

{

  $file=$request->file('image');

  $new_name = rand(). '.' .

  $path=public_path().'/images';

  $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();

  $file->move($path, $name);

  $data=$name;

}

$data=array(

'productname'=> $request->input('productname'),

'image'=> $name,

'price'=> $request->input('price'),

'category_id'=> $request->input('category_id')

 );



Product::where('id', $id)

  ->update($data); 

  return redirect('/item')->with('info','Product updated successfuly!');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only updating the product details without uploading an image, then if($request->hasfile('image')) becomes false, as $name variable is not getting assigned. Try this..

```
public function productupdate(Request $request, $id) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'productname' => 'required',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg|max:10000',
            'price' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required'
        ]);

        $data = array(
            'productname' => $request->input('productname'),
            'image' => null,
            'price' => $request->input('price'),
            'category_id' => $request->input('category_id')
        );

        if ($request->hasfile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $path = public_path() . '/images';
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($path, $name);
            $data['image'] = $name;
        }

        Product::where('id', $id)

            ->update($data);

        return redirect('/item')->with('info', 'Product updated successfully!');
}
```